# How to draw outside canvas and make bitmap of it?

Tags: android, canvas, view, bitmap

I am drawing some rows of text. After a couple of rows, it goes offscreen. What i want to do is capture all the rows(also the rows outside the canvas) in a bitmap.

```
I have the code below which only works for within the canvas(screen).

    private class DeciderView extends View {

        private Paint paint;
        String text = "";
        String[] options = { "een", "twee", "drie", "vier", "vijf", "zes", "zeven", "acht",
                "negen", "tien", "elf", "twaalf", "dertien", "vertien", "vijftien" };

        public DeciderView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // Keep screen on
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            // Remove title bar
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            // Remove notification bar
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setTextSize(75);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

            setDrawingCacheQuality(DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

        }

        private void drawInput(Canvas canvas) {
            Paint p = new Paint();
            p.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            p.setTextSize(canvas.getWidth() / 10f);
            p.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            float xText = canvas.getWidth() / 2f;

            float yText = (canvas.getHeight() / 4f);
            for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                text += options[i] + "\n";
            }
            for (String line : text.split("\n")) {
                canvas.drawText(line, xText, yText, p);
                yText -= (p.ascent() + p.descent()) * 2.5f;

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            drawInput(canvas);

            this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getDrawingCache());
            b = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), false);

            try {
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(
                        new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                                + "/Pictures/aaaaa.jpg")));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (b != null) {
                b.recycle();
                b = null;
            }
        }

    }
```

So basically i want to make a bitmap from all the rows, even if the rows are drawn outside the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just draw directly to the bitmap?  You can create a new Canvas that has a bitmap backing it.  You use the normal canvas draw commands, and the output will be written to the bitmap rather than the screen.  If you also want to draw it to the screen, just draw the new bitmap to the screen at the end.  To do this all you need is

```
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. The only problem i'm having is that the quality of the bitmap is lower after saving it to de sdcard.